# C++ - Xcode "Inline Function Expansion" optimization feature like in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, optimization

I am programming a C++ application in Xcode, and I was wondering if there is such a feature in Xcode alike the Visual Studio optimization tool: "Inline Function Expansion"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an MSVC++ or Xcode user but it seems "Inline Function Expansion" can control inlining. I think Xcode uses either [`clang`](http://clang.llvm.org/) or [`gcc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/): both of these compilers have similar approaches to inlining. For `gcc` there are, e.g., the following options (there are a couple of more options which can affect inlining decisions):

- `-fno-inline` disables inlining (except for functions with an attribute indicating that they shall always be inlined)
- `-finline-small-functions` enables inlining of functions which would be bigger when actually called (gets enabled with `-O2`)
- `-finline-functions` enables inlining of non-`inline` functions (gets enabled with `-O3`)
- `-flto` can enable inlining of functions across multiple translation units

Comment: I tried all of them, but Xcode gave me the warning "optimization flag (flag) is not supported"

Answer (score -1):

I was also looking into this as I was following along with a c++ tutorial that had lots of templates in an inline file. I tried putting all the templates (with their implementations) into the header file and it worked perfectly.

D.